# Formas de informar o endereço

Tags: c#, asp.net, formulário, lógica

Boa tarde pessoas,

Tenho uma dúvida não muito técnica, e sim de formas de pegar uma informação.

Aqui na empresa temos um formulário para os nossos usuários informarem endereços de atendimento. Este formulário tem a opção automática e manual.

A de forma automática tem somente um campo, onde ele digita o endereço, clica num botão, o sistema busca o endereço no google e retorna, caso encontre. (EX: Avenida Paulista, 1800, Jardins, São Paulo)

Caso não encontre, o usuário pode informar manualmente, onde temos: 4 Dropdown (Estado, Cidade, Bairro e Região) e 4 TextBox (Endereço, número, complemento, Cep).

A dúvida é: estamos numa reformulação da pesquisa, faremos a parte automática via API Javascript do google, de forma mais intuitiva e rápida, mas ainda precisamos de um informe manual, caso o google não ache o endereço. Quais outras formas teria de pegar um endereço de forma completa, sem que sejam com 8 componentes? Acaba ficando muito lento, indo ao banco buscar a cidade, bairro, região. Queríamos algo mais prático, e não estamos conseguindo pensar em nada.

Obrigado.

Comment: Eu costumo usar webservice de cep, mas não puxo o endereço detalhado. Deixo a caixa do CEP e pego somente UF e Cidade - que esses geralmente vêm bem certinhos -  e elimino a digitação ou select de dois campos.
Podes usar para preencher a rua também, e deixar a opção do usuário corrigir isso, caso venha com erro.

Dá uma olhada: http://viacep.com.br/exemplo/jquery/

Comment: Não entendi qual o problema, principalmente de fazer 8 pesquisas. Se estiver feito certo levará alguns poucos milissegundos. Se estiver demorando muito, tem algo muito errado, mas a pergunta não é sobre isto.

Comment: Temos uma restrição de utilizar webservices externos (exceção do google), mas seria interessante se tivessemos uma base de CEPs aqui na empresa pra fazer a pesquisa. Obrigado.

Comment: @bigown não faz 8 pesquisas. As pesquisas são somente para os dropdowns, são 4 pesquisas. Mas as 4 pesquisas passam por um WCF que fica em outro servidor para buscar as infos, além de ajudar a tela não é nem um pouco leve. Então sim, esses 4 carregamentos demoram mais do que desejado na tela do usuário

Comment: Então tem algo errado, o problema não é o fluxo e sim como está desenvolvendo. Alguma parte está fazendo coisas que não deve. A única experiência que tive com WCF foi pra tomar a decisão de nunca mais por a mão nisto. Mas não sei se é a maior explicação. Ou seja, o problema real não está na pergunta. E acho que não tem o que fazer para melhorar alguma coisa a não ser consertar o problema no código.